# add_submenu_page in Wordpress not working when called alone

Tags: wordpress

What I'm trying to do is,

```
function whatever () {
  add_menu_page('correct arguments');
}    

function whatever2 () {
  add_submenu_page('correct arguments');
  add_submenu_page('correct arguments');
  add_submenu_page('correct arguments');
  add_submenu_page('correct arguments');
}
```

and I'm calling both the whatever's at different times , and of course I'm calling the first whatever first and then the second whatever with proper `add_action` wrapping. So thanks in advance :)

Comment: ... so you're saying all arguments and all calls are done correctly. Great, then it will work. If you want actual help you should include what you actually wrote as `add_action` calls and what the arguments are and not just assume "correct arguments"

Comment: when will you call this function `whatever2 `?

Comment: the reason why Im saying that they are correct is because,, when I combine the contents of those two functions into one function, i.e. 

when I call `add_menu_page` and then all the `add_submenu_page` s, it works perfectly.


All I want is some way to call `add_menu_page` 

and then call `add_submenu_page` s some other time .


My Idea is to call whatever2 inside another class constructors to add dynamic sub pages based on the available classes,